# Get actual date into seconds on iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm making an app where I need to get the actual date (`[NSDate date]`) into seconds since 1970 (`timeIntervalSince1970`). But I don't manage to get it working, how should it be done?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what the result was.

Comment: I didn't managed to compile, I've tried using NSTimeInterval *seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];` but IDK, I'm not used to NSDate

Comment: and what was the error and the actual code (it helps others to be able to compile and test code on their systems)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]
```

Note that NSTimeInterval is actually a `double` value, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
double intrval=[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

-(NSDate*)dateFromDouble:(double) intrval{
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:intrval];  
}
```